# I downoaded articles from libgen (didn't know was illegal) and it seems that advisor used them to publish his work

Tags: publications, advisor, ethics, undergraduate, legal-issues

I did download some articles from libgen and by then I didn't know it wasn't right to do so, well some people say that there's no problem but honestly I think it is and I'm scared for what this articles where used for without me knowing about it.

Short story

I downloaded articles. I started writing my protocol thesis with advisor/professor supervision, based on parts of these articles. Advisor then asked me to do a summary of some of them, I did it and then sent it to his mail. We then stopped working due to him "I'm very busy, lot of work at uni, COVID-19" (I then realize he was lying, he was indeed working on my topic preparing to show it as his *own* work) and I said "don't worry, I understand". For some time I kept studying on my own until I felt lost with no direction and it was during this time also that I knew that the articles and content from libgen is, in general, illegal to use. I didn't scare, I just thought that I had nothing on my protocol since it's based on libgen content. I just thought on commenting this to advisor next time I saw him (personally, didn't want to say this through mail) and ask permission or purchase if needed, the articles that I was going to use. About 3 months later (end of august) since the last message of advisor, he said "Sorry for speaking until now, I've been working on the topic, I've structured how your thesis would be, are you still interested on working?" I said "I understand, don't worry. How the structure of my thesis is (perhaps here was the time to say: stop working on it there's something I need to tell you, but I didn't, I didn't think things would go further whiout telling me previously)? Yes, although right now I'm taking a summer course" (course that started at beginning of august). A month passed and I never got a reply. A few days ago, I realized that advisor is going to give a talk (within days) about my thesis topic.

So say we planned to work on article X, which contained methods w,x about topic AB, BC, CD using Y.

He plans to give a talk about topic "x applied on AB, BC, CD"  and on his summary, he mentioned parts contained on my protocol that I proposed, i.e. my original ideas, and also he plans to use Y aswell, not sure if the same Y as mine, wouldn't surprise me if it's the same Y.

Why did he steal my work? Because it is new, this kind of works have been done in other parts of the world but not on ours. But there's a major problem that really worries me, as I said this -work on my protocol (which was never completed nor registered)- it's based of articles that I downloaded from libgen, fortunatelly only 5 of them are in the case of "need to purchase, free to *reuse* on thesis/dissertation but need to comply some terms", the rest of them, afaiu, are free to use, they are on ResearchGate and you can download them.

Notice that **I** am not the one publishing anything, I'm not giving a talk, I would never use work taken without permisson or withouth purchasing when authors are requiring this actions for their works. The thing that I did was to take part of some from these restricted articles for my protocol and a summary, and sent to advisor. And it's highly likely that these content is going to be used to give a talk and to publish a paper. Am I in trouble? Am I in legal troubles?

Please help me, I don't know what to do. I don't want to comment this to advisor, not even personally if I could, I don't trust at all in this person.

Comment: I think we had a question before with the conclusion that citing papers obtained via scihub is perfectly fine. The rest seems to be some unclear mess about advisor-advisee authorship rights.

Comment: Obligatory link: https://custodians.online/

Comment: I am not quite sure your supervisor did what you think he did, but—and it is always a good idea—what about some chill? Take a break, dedicate some time to your hobby, go hiking, etc. I am serious. Psychological health is important.

Comment: Oleg, he did what I said he did. I commented this issue of advisor stelaing my work to another professor and he agreeed with me, with some slight differences of wording, she told me that "he is an opportunistic". But at this point my mind is not into that. It hurts yes, I still cannot believe it, yes. Right now I'm into the other problem of legal things

Comment: I don't understand .... Reading between the lines and trying to understand the situation, it appears as if the advisor finally had gotten around to putting the time in on reviewing and revising and reworking what the advisee had submitted. Is that a bad thing? Is the talk the advisor giving a talk to a conference where the advisee is not being mentioned? Or is it some local talk like seminar or colloquium?

Comment: Carol, there was never something to call 'work' thanks to him "not having time". We starting by writting first the protocol (90% mine), the next thing was the thesis writting. I was very interested in working and I used to ask lots of questions, like what's next? what do I do? why this? I don't get it. He was always like meh..yes, idk, keep searching, i'm too busy due uni/cov. I accepted all of these because I trusted him and had good references. Next thing I know is: he is about to give a talk (International congress) about my thesis topic and until today he hasn't said a word to me about it.

Comment: Is it really necessary to downvote this beginning researcher's question so much?

Answer (score 14):

I really don't think you should worry about the fact that you downloaded articles from libgen or similar websites. Nobody is going to come arrest you because of that... I doubt anyone will know the articles were illegally downloaded and I highly doubt anyone will be enforcing copyright laws to the point where you will see any consequences. If you think it's wrong, then just don't do it in the future, but I am pretty sure that most academics get "illegal" articles from the internet or their peers every once in a while, cite them in their work, and don't think twice about it and most people will not even judge you for it.

I wouldn't mention it to your advisor, or anyone else for that matter because it really isn't a big enough deal to feel any stress over.

I think the real problem is your advisor stealing your work, as you say. But that is a different question.

To add to the potential consequences: The worst thing that will happen to you is your internet company might send you an email threatening to fine you or something. If you stop the illegal downloads, (or get a VPN/other ways of making your traffic anonymous), they will not pursue the issue any further. At least that has been my experience with pirating things in the past.

Comment: Madam/sir after what happened.. do you think that am I going to go back to libgen? and worst to download? NO way I'll be back there. I was really really but really scared for what happened. This is how I felt the situation: I found recipes to cook, didn't know it was stolen recipes (I should have known, too good to be for free..). I started preparing ingredients, then I knew the recipes were obtained illegally. So let's ask permission to obtain them correctly, and so no problem. Meanwhile advisor was analyzing the recipes and preparing to produce new food, he likely will obtain money from it

Comment: It's like stolen money, I didn't know it was stolen, I planned to "give back" or return back or ask permission to use it or something, but I didn't see to come that someone else was preparing to use this money. I thought I was the only one that had 'control' over it, so no fear that something could go wrong

Comment: I am not sure what field you are in, but I am in math. If I get a method to solve a PDE from an illegally downloaded article, that does *not* mean I am not allowed to use the method. If I make money off of it, nothing changes. That's just not how academic research works. That might be how the business world works, but we need the free exchange of ideas in order to make progress in science. 

Suppose you got the articles legally and then shared them with your advisor, and your advisor expanded the results and made money off of it, there would be nothing wrong with that.

Comment: My point is, the thing that is illegal is the downloading itself. Not the using of the ideas. And the downloading by and large has very minimal consequences, if any.

Comment: Also, by and large, you would not need "permission" to use a result that is in a public paper available on the internet even if it's behind a paywall. Unless I have some big misconceptions about how things work in your field. Of course you should cite the paper where you got the result you're using, and that does a lot of good for the researchers who discovered the result. But you don't need to ask permission.

Comment: Ok, I got your point, thank you for the relief answer and comments. In any case, I mean worst case scenario, there where only little parts that I used on my protocol (which was never submitted to authorities, and I'll never going to submit unless I've obtained these 5 articles properly) and a half page of summary. But then again... they likely were used and expanded, maybe like a bomb :/

Comment: pictorexcrucia, you say that the illegal is the downloading, is there a way to "undownload"?

Comment: Lol @user, no there is no way to undownload! That's ridiculous. 

In fact, if you paid for the article, and then downloaded an illegal copy, and someone found out and took you to court, they would have an extremely difficult time getting you charged with anything. Seriously, you didn't really do anything wrong and I really think you can relax. It's not like the authors of the paper are suffering because you didn't pay. They will benefit a lot more from getting some citations than you paying the journal.

Comment: ok ok, I understand. I'm sorry for this, I honestly know nothing about how the scientific environment works. I heard the word _illegal_ and I got scared. It was traumatic, and even if you say nothing happens I'm not downloading this content ever again. I even stopped thinking about my work ideas that he stole from me. Thanks again, God bless you!

Answer (score 5):

I am not entirely sure what the problem is or what you are enquiring about. As pointed out by others there seem to be two different issues:

1. You downloading articles from libgen (or scihub for that matter)
2. Your relation with your supervisor and how to get credit for work you've done.

The first point is fairly simple. It may be illegal to download articles from libgen and the likes (depending on the jurisdiction). But using this content in other scientific papers and projects is perfectly fine **as long as it is properly referenced**.

As for the second point, you may want to talk with your supervisor as to how he thinks to share credit for the work. If you have indeed contributed to the research or project your contribution should be acknowledged. If a paper gets published with significant input from you but without you being mentioned could be a violation of ethics codes.

Comment: I'm not the one who did this "But using this content in other scientific papers and projects is perfectly fine as long as it is properly referenced." he did it, and will share it on the talk. I'm not sure if something could be done about _sharing credit_. First, the origin of the 5 papers was... well you know. I, by no means, want credit for this. Second, we never concreted anything about _work_, even tho the thesis topic idea and other things were completely mine, formally because he was always "busy"

Comment: You still seem to miss the point: No one cares or has to care where you got the papers from in the first place. If your supervisor shares his insights in a talk and cites the papers you downloaded there is no problem with that. He could simply go back and download the papers himself from the journal websites or ask the authors for copies. That's absolutely fine. As to whether or not you deserve credit for "your idea" depends on what you really provided and whether or not that idea was unique and original.

Answer (score 0):

Besides everything that has already been said, the biggest problem is stealing someone's finished work without referring to the original author. However, you did not do this. The moral deviant here isn't you - and no legal consequences are going to will to you.

Let me try to explain why.

The open-access or on libgen books are more downloaded and cited than others behind the paywalls. A lot of studies are finding this (e.g. see https://blogs.lse.ac.uk/impactofsocialsciences/2017/11/22/open-access-books-are-downloaded-cited-and-mentioned-more-than-non-oa-books). And considering that the scientists will do their jobs aiming large range of readers as well they are already paid for the development of their studies by private or public institutions, seems like ok if you read books from libgen and do the reference. Imagine that you could borrow the book from one friend or the library school.

Besides that, assuming you are not making any harm to nobody as well as helping to amplify the reach of those studies, in fact, you are helping people to access knowledge. (And knowledge must be free for all!!)

Nevertheless, if you not confident yet and have the conditions to reimburse, so you could just send the money directly to the author. Because, in the end, she/he receives a little part of the price!!! If you take into account that the big publishers are who retaining the money and not the authors, using libgen and sci-hub is a big favor for the authors.

It is especially true outside of renamed US and EU universities, where we don't have money to access knowledge and don't have a choice. Is very common to ask for the authors for their work if isn't present on the web for free.

Resuming:

- The money from the sales goes almost all to the editors.
- Science needs been free to disseminate and contribute to the progress of knowledge.
- As the first goal, authors want more to amplify their reach than get rich.
- Ok, that's necessary some kind of retribution to the scientists work, but the books are a very little part of their budget.
- And there is no possibility for many young or/and poor researchers to buy books.
- by the end, you could read them at the library or even borrowing.