# Linking stackexchange account with answers that have cited papers without access while applying for research opportunities

Tags: research-undergraduate, internship

I am a sophomore currently and was active pre-university on one of the daughter sites. While answering questions, I would reach upon specific research papers, paywalled. I broke through them
using means that are not so legal.

My answers reflect the primary reasons and interests as to why I want to research in that specific field are on that account.

Is it advisable to refer to my StackExchange account in my cover letter?

I have cited all articles properly; however, screenshots have been posted in many answers.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/stack-overflow-reputation-in-cv

Comment: I do not think the linked question is a duplicate. The linked question asks whether Stack Exchange reputation can be showcased as an achievement in the CV, for an application unrelated to their online activity. The OP here wants to use their posts to motivate their research interests, and the focus of the question is on the fact that they accessed their references through illegal means. Even if the answer is "don't talk about your posts at all", the reasoning for advising this will have to be different from that used in the proposed duplicate.

Comment: Regarding the "illegal" papers, you can possibly find some answers in here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/125570/citing-paywalled-articles-accessed-via-illegal-web-sharing and here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/156331/i-downoaded-articles-from-libgen-didnt-know-was-illegal-and-it-seems-that-adv

Comment: I'm confused. How would anyone know whether your access to articles pre-university was by "not so legal" means? For all that anyone knows, you may have taken classes at a nearby university while in high school (something I did, but this was pre-internet) and this gave you legal access to the articles. Or you may have (legally) made photocopies of the articles at a nearby university library, something I've done quite a lot over the years. Is your concern that the screenshots you posted indicate "not so legal" means?

Comment: Yes @DaveLRenfro "Is your concern that the screenshots you posted indicate "not so legal" means?" this is exactly what I wanted to ask about. On a side note is it advisable not to link your SE account? I do not want to show off my reputation or anything of that sort simply show that I have been interested in xyz topic for a long time.