# Is publishing paper containing information acquired from sites such as Sci-Hub illegal?

Tags: journals, paper-submission, copyright, legal-issues, sci-hub

There are already some discussions on whether it's illegal to use Sci-Hub for research purposes, such as in [this Academia SE thread](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/87688/what-are-the-consequences-of-using-sci-hub).

But [one answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/111057/) and comments there open up another question: Is it illegal to publish a paper containing information or data acquired from such sites such as Sci-Hub and library genesis (if downloading papers from where is deemed illegal)? One argument for this is one should not use information acquired via illegal means. Then in strict sense we cannot even cite a paper downloaded there. I cannot come up with a counterargument to that now though.

Comment: IANAL, but it's not illegal to perform well at your job just because you broke the speed limit in order to get to work on time.  The two situations seem analogous to me.  (And I think I'd argue that speeding is a more serious offence than downloading an infringing copy of paper from scihub.)

Comment: The counterargument would be the absence of a law that forbids it. As far as I know (IANAL), no country has a law that forbids using an illegally downloaded paper for research purposes. (The downloading itself is a completely different matter.)

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/156331/68109

Comment: I read somewhere that most people who access Sci-Hub work for an organization/university with a valid subscription to a publisher's database.  One reason is because some institutions require multiple logins to gain access to a database.  As for Sci-Hub, one just have to copy and paste a DoI.  Also, how would somebody know that the cited papers from Sci-Hub?  good luck finding that out!  Lastly, only publishers would care about Sci-Hub.  They won't go after authors because doing so means they bite the hand that feeds them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to consult a lawyer for this, but it isn't the *publishing* that is illegal, per se. How you acquired certain information might have legal implications, and how you quote and cite might have ethical implications, of course. But both of those are independent of publishing.

Republishing copyright material is illegal in a lot of places, but I don't think that is exactly what you mean. Such republishing is illegal even if you obtain the original properly.

Answering such questions here is, however, a down vote magnet for some reason, so I hesitate to say more.

I will note, however, that copyright violation is almost entirely a civil matter. If you infringe someones copyright it is up to them to try to defend their rights via a lawsuit. And, then, they have to notice it, of course. There are some [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyright_infringement#Criminal_law) to this general rule, of course, and Disney would like to have anyone abusing their "Mickey Mouse" copyright thrown in jail until the copyright expires and which they also work to extend to infinity. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re asking about publishing a paper using papers downloaded illegally, it’s nearly impossible for anyone who reviews your work to know whether the papers were illicitly obtained. It’s not illegal (the cops won’t come after you), but conducting research using illegal sources almost certainly violates your university’s code of conduct. If you’re supported by a grant, then your funding agency has a code of conduct that you most likely violated. The consequences of such violations can be severe - just like they would be for any other academic misconduct.

I actually interpreted the question differently: can you write a paper *about* the data in SciHub? The answer to that is probably yes (and it can be really interesting!). In the book *Freakonomics*, the authors describe a grad student studying the economics of a gang’s organization and business model. Gang membership is clearly illegal, studying them is not!